# Looping through the cursor in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a procedure in T-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_QC1
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tablename varchar(100);
    DECLARE @sfilename varchar(100);
    DECLARE @rread varchar(100);
    DECLARE @rwrite varchar(100);
    DECLARE @sserver varchar(100);
    DECLARE @dbname varchar(100);

    DECLARE cur_tracking CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            [TableName],
            sfilename,
            [RecordsRead],
            [RecordsWritten],
            [SQLServer],
            [SQLDatabase]
        FROM 
            [ADataTracker].[dbo].[TrackerLoadLog] 
        WHERE
            LOWER(datagroup) LIKE '%Oracle RMS%'
            AND SUBSTRING(sfilename, 1, 10) = '2022-03-16'

    OPEN cur_tracking;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tracking INTO @tablename, @sfilename, @rread, @rwrite, @sserver, @dbname;

    WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            sfilename, COUNT(*) 
        FROM
            @sserver + '.dbo.' + @dbname 
        WHERE
            sfilename = @sfilename 
        GROUP BY 
            sfilename

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tracking INTO @tablename, @sfilename, @rread, @rwrite, @sserver, @dbname;
    END;

    CLOSE cur_tracking;
    DEALLOCATE cur_tracking;
END
```

The cursor `cur_tracking` is holding the data (just showing 1 record)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TableName       |sfilename                    | RecordsRead |RecordsWritten |SQLServer                      |SQLDatabase  |
History         |2022-03-16\20220316032322.dat| 5819560     |5819560        |a.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com |DataRms_Back |
```

So the cursor is having all the information of server, Databasename, tablename. I want to go to those each `server.db.table` and retrieve the information using these cursor elements:

```
SELECT sfilename, COUNT(*) 
FROM @sserver + '.dbo.' + @dbname 
WHERE sfilename = @sfilename 
GROUP BY sfilename
```

But I get an error:

> invalid column name sfilename
> must declare the table variable @sserver

Comment: `LOWER(datagroup) LIKE '%Oracle RMS%'` Look again at the code you wrote. Does using LOWER here make **any sense**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is never going to work:

```
select sfilename,count(*) from @sserver+'.dbo.'+@dbname
```

You can't parameterize entity names like this (also database comes before schema, and you missed `@tablename` entirely).

Instead you can do:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @exec nvarchar(1000);

...
  -- then inside the cursor:
  SET @sql = N'select sfilename = @sfilename,count(*)  
           FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)
           + N' WHERE sfilename = @sfilename;';

  SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

  EXEC @exec @sql, N'@sfilename varchar(100)', @sfilename;
```

Note that all of these need to be `nvarchar(128)`, and you can use the same `DECLARE` for multiple variables to lighten eye strain:

```
DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(128),
        @sfilename nvarchar(128),
        @dbname    nvarchar(128);
```

Please review [this collection of links](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql).

Comment: Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure usp_QC1, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 38]
Could not find server 'a.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: I got this error after putting your script

Comment: @DikshitKarki The error message is telling you the problem, and it has nothing to do with the code, you have servers listed in the table that you're never going to be able to connect to in this way without creating linked servers to all of them. SQL Server can't just go connect to random servers on the Internet (or even random servers inside your network). Try for yourself: `SELECT * FROM [a.stg.sql.ccaintranet.com].master.sys.databases;` will lead to the same error, until you create a linked server. Again, nothing to do with my code.

Comment: i will be running procedure  in the same server.. so server part can be neglected. Can you please modify the code so that dbo.tablename will work.. since i will be running in this same server

Comment: @DikshitKarki Ok, so the problem is different from the question? Try just removing the `QUOTENAME(@sserver) + N'.'` bit. And change the question, if `@sserver` isn't part of the problem, it shouldn't be part of the question.

Comment: Hi @aaron it worked, I also need sfilename,count(*) data to be stored in variable so that i can store it into new table?

Comment: @DikshitKarki Please stop changing the question and adding new requirements. Your initial query doesn't assign to variables or perform an insert, it just selects. So we can't guess requirements after the fact and it is unfair to constantly change them (these are called [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/165455)). Did you try just `INSERT dbo.SomeOtherTable(columns) EXEC @exec @sql, N'@sfilename varchar(100)', @sfilename;`? Why do you need variables to insert?